# Uncaught SyntaxError: "Unexpected token { "

Tags: html, ajax

I took over a html code and it needs to be improved.

There is an error at a code :

```
 var lastJsonValue = {input: {{data|JSON}} };
```

This is used for Ajax. And the error is

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

I upload source code to : https://www.dropbox.com/s/g29caunvunmn5cy/dev.html?dl=0

The error code is at line 848

I have no idea of it. Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot!

[This question is closed]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That isn't HTML.

It is a template language (I can't tell you which one, there are several with syntax along those lines) which, when run (with suitable input `data`) through an appropriate template engine, will generate JavaScript.

You need to run it through the template engine.